# People usually use "typical" in place of using "difficult". Does "typical" also mean "difficult"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, adjectives

*Typical* actually means "of a particular type" but that particular type may not be difficult.
What do you people think?

Comment: Could you please provide more context, or an example?

Comment: @JonPurdy, I'm guessing that it's something like "Oh, that's just *typical*!", which as @Tom suggests is an expression of dissatisfaction rather than difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical does not mean difficult. If something — a task, say, like icing a cake — is usually easy, it would be typical for it to be easy. *Difficult*, however, would never mean *easy*.

*Typical* means

> having the distinctive qualities of a particular type of person or thing

Those qualities might be difficulty, easiness, awkwardness, oddness, friendliness, whatever: the point is, they would be representative of a type.

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't mean the same thing.

People may however use "typical" to express dissatisfaction with something. For example:

"Typical Jim, he's always late"

or

"Typical, I knew I was going to fall into that cake, my day is ruined".

Comment: Note that this is still related to typical, in that it generally means "That person (even myself) has once again done something annoying/bad, something that is *typical* of them". (It *is* especially annoying when someone does something and you 'know' in advance they're going to do it, and they do it anyway!)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, "typical" does not mean "difficult".  There are no common English idioms where this is the case, either.

But I wonder if the people who "usually" use this word are not actually just mispronouncing "difficult".  Or possibly you are mis-hearing "difficult" as "typical".  There are some common consonant mutations involved d --> t, f --> p, possibly elision of the final "t".  I once had Tibetan Buddhist monk as a teacher, and I can imagine him pronouncing "difficult" this way.

Comment: I remember the newsstand vendor who used to say "eighty pie" when I bought something that cost $0.85.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the word *typical* makes it seem like you're being characterized into a position that may not be true. A false perception.